# Where to set my xcode path

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to convince my computer that I have development tools installed and when I type the command "xcode-select --install" i receive the following and was wondering where to set the path?

> xcode-select: Report or change the path to the active
>                 Xcode installation for this machine.
>
> Usage: xcode-select --print-path
>              Prints the path of the active Xcode folder
>      or: xcode-select --switch 
>          Sets the path for the active Xcode folder
>      or: xcode-select --version
>              Prints the version of xcode-select"

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You'd have to set the path to "Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" directory (where xcode has been installed)

```
$ xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

This requires root permissions.

Comment: That is the path that my xcode is set to but my computer still will not recognize that I have the development tools installed

Comment: Brew, the popular package manager tool for Mac OS is wreaking havoc on xcode-select for some reason. I came here after installing brew on a system with Xcode installed. It broke build pipeline commands. This error would appear: $ xed .
xcode-select: error: tool 'xed' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Answer (score 10):

Open Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Select your Xcode version from the dropdown and exit Xcode